# Is multi index search possible with ongr.io's ElasticSearchBundle?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, ongr

I'm looking into ongr.io's [ElasticSearchBundle](https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchBundle) but can't find a way to perform a multi index search or query. Am I overlooking something or is it just not possible (yet)?

According to the docs, you specify the index you're using in your [configuration](https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration.md) and not when [performing the search](https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/search.md)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate manager for the multi-index search purpose and define index name separated by the comma.

```
connections:
    default:
        hosts:
            - 127.0.0.1:9200
        index_name: "firstIndex,secondIndex"
```

Comment: Cool. And would that work easily or would there be any downsides to doing this?

Comment: This is the flexibility of elasticsearch database. In ElasticsearchBundle I would recommend to create a separate manager for multi-index search, otherwise if you will try to write operation it will create documents in both index or throw an exception if something will be wrong with config etc.